# How to use a particular variable for a year and match those to other years?

Tags: r, tidyverse

In the panel data, I have district codes for the year 2009-10. However, based on the common id variable, I want the same district codes to go for the other rounds as well (2014 to 2019). I cannot think of any way of doing it in R. Any leads or suggestions would be appreciated.

```
data <- tibble::tibble(
  Year = rep(c("2010", "2014", "2015"), each = 5L),
  id = c(
    10001, 10002, 10003, 10004, 10005, 100001, 100002, 100003, 100004, 100005,
    100001, 100002, 100003, 100004, 100005
  ),
  dist = rep(c(13, NA), c(5L, 10L))
)
```

Comment: Does the posted data work on your system?

Comment: @AndreWildberg Sorry, I have reposted the data example

Comment: Do you want to replace `NA` by `dist` based on `id`? Right now there's no shared `id` between the years. Or simply replace `NA` with 13?

Comment: @AndreWildberg I want to replace NA by dist based on id in my unbalanced panel

Answer (score 0):

If you meant to replace `NA`s with *dist* values from other years with shared `id`s

Using a slightly modified data set

```
df
# A tibble: 15 × 3
   Year      id  dist
   <chr>  <dbl> <dbl>
 1 2010  100001    13
 2 2010  100002    13
 3 2010  100003    13
 4 2010  100004    13
 5 2010  100005    13
 6 2014  100001    NA
 7 2014  100002    NA
 8 2014  100003    NA
 9 2014  100004    NA
10 2014  100005    NA
11 2015  100001    NA
12 2015  100002    NA
13 2015  100003    NA
14 2015  100004    NA
15 2015  100005    NA
```

Using `fill`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  fill(dist) %>% 
  ungroup()
# A tibble: 15 × 3
   Year      id  dist
   <chr>  <dbl> <dbl>
 1 2010  100001    13
 2 2010  100002    13
 3 2010  100003    13
 4 2010  100004    13
 5 2010  100005    13
 6 2014  100001    13
 7 2014  100002    13
 8 2014  100003    13
 9 2014  100004    13
10 2014  100005    13
11 2015  100001    13
12 2015  100002    13
13 2015  100003    13
14 2015  100004    13
15 2015  100005    13
```

##### Data

```
df <- structure(list(Year = structure(c("2010", "2010", "2010", "2010", 
"2010", "2014", "2014", "2014", "2014", "2014", "2015", "2015", 
"2015", "2015", "2015"), label = "Year", format.stata = "%-12s"), 
    id = structure(c(100001, 100002, 100003, 100004, 100005, 
    100001, 100002, 100003, 100004, 100005, 100001, 100002, 100003, 
    100004, 100005), label = "DSL", format.stata = "%10.0g"), 
    dist = structure(c(13, 13, 13, 13, 13, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), label = "District Code", format.stata = "%2.0f")), 
    row.names = c(NA, -15L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: Thank you for this, the codes gave me NAs in dist for the Years other than 2010

Comment: Probably because the ids are different. Do you have a second data set?  Can you please post an expected output in your original question? That might make it easier to see how to get the desired result.